# cant set css stylesheet height, width on div from stylesheet

Tags: html, css

UPDATE: I figured out what is happening. My hosts (ipage.com) has some type of caching where even after you update the css and clear your cache it will show the old one for a long time. If you web search "ipage css refresh" you can read more about it.

RESOLVED: when I put www.domain.com it shows an old stylesheet I had that's not even on the host anymore. domain.com however works fine. I don't know why this is but I'm looking into it. Thank you all for your help.

I can't seem to set the height and width of my div. If i put style inside the tag it works, but from the style-sheet it doesn't. Thanks.

---

```
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/stylesheet1.css">
        <title>website</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="menu" >
            <b>item1</b>
            <br>
            <b>item2</b>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

the css is:

```
#menu {
    display          : inline-block;
    background-color : blue;
    height           : 200px;
    width            : 100px;
}
```

Comment: If you view the page source and click the link to the stylesheet, do you see the CSS?

Comment: yes I see the color attribute but not the height and width attributes

Comment: a) Always use a doctype. Otherwise, some browsers will emulate errors from very old versions (see "quirks mode"). b) that meta-tag is only valid if you're using the HTML5 doctype (and use html5 of course). c) using `b` instead of `strong`is semantically wrong in 99% of all cases.

Comment: Here is jsfiddle of your html http://jsfiddle.net/XH68r/    Can you elobrate what are you trying to achieve exacly

Comment: Note that the fiddle @NullSoulException provided actually works :)

Comment: Im a beginner. Im just trying to get the stylesheet working.

Comment: WHen i view page source and click link to the stylesheet there is either an old version of the stylesheet not including height and width or the browser is totally ignoring height and width and yet displaying a background-color with a color I had on a previous style sheet. On my host however the current stylesheet was ftp overwritten and shows correct.

Comment: The stylesheet is in root directory along with .php file

Comment: CLear your browsers cache then ;) This should fore it to relaod the stylesheet from the server.

Comment: I agree with @Johannes H. Is this case solved? =)

Answer (score 0):

Just a guess: Does the stylesheet really reside inside the root folder of your domain, or is it in some sub-directory?
`/stylesheet1.css` is an absolute path... The leading slash indicates the root folder.
Maybe you meant `stylesheet1.css`, which refers to a file in the same folder as the html page?

Answer (score 0):

well, first check either your browser can get the stylesheet,
use [firebug extension](http://getfirebug.com) (if you are using firefox, if you are using chrome no need to install firebug ) then press `F12`  and check whether the browser can get the stylesheet file or get an 404 error.

I think the problem is that the browser cannot get the file, thus any changes that you create inside the file won't do anything.

Comment: Or it's really just the cache, especially if changing the path worked (see edit of the question), as it appears to be a new file and is loaded again.

Comment: if it does try force reload `ctrl+F5` or `ctrl+shift+R` (forgot which is firefox and which is chrome ) :p

Answer (score -1):

Is the stylesheet in the root directory of your website? Make sure you can view the stylesheet by visiting it's url in the browser.

Comment: Already solved, and we already had that suggestion 30 minutes ago. :)